# menu hovering and padding on top and bottom

Tags: html, css

i've a menu  with sub menus in it, i've added border at bottom while hovering but when i  hover on the menu the menu height increases a bit, the whole menu takes a space at top and bottom when i put it in a div.

here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/p7Nsf/

```
<div class="head"></div>

<div class="menudiv">
<div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">School</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Vision and Mission </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Principal’s desk</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Management</a>
                        </ul> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Admission</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Download application form</a></li>
                        </ul> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">School Calander</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News & Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>               
            </ul>
        </div>
</div><!-- menu div ends-->

<div class="foot"></div>
```

CSS

```
.menudiv
{
    width:980px;
}

.menu {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
}

.menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;

}

.menu ul {
    background: #111312;

    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    border:3px solid #111312;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;

}
.menu ul:after {
    content: ""; 
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
}

.menu ul li {
    float: left;
}
.menu ul li:hover {
    background: #111312;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
.menu ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

.menu ul li a {
    display: block; 
    padding-top: 10px;     padding-left: 25px;     padding-right: 25px;     padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #fff; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul ul {
    background: #111312;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
}
.menu ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    color:#000;
    display: block; 
}   
.menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #111312;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    top:0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid pink; 
    position: relative;
}

.menu ul ul ul li a { 
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block; 
}

.menu ul ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #95CEF1;
  color: #000;
}

.menu ul ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    top:0;
}

.head
{
   width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background:#789;
}

.foot
{
   width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background:#123;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, your menu item jumps because you are adding border to the item so it increases its height by the 3 px border

```
.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p7Nsf/1/

reduce padding on the anchor to compensate for the 3px

```
.menu ul li a {
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p7Nsf/2/

Update

```
.menu ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #111312;
    border: 3px solid #111312;
    display: inline-table;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

I removed the display prop

http://jsfiddle.net/p7Nsf/4/

Comment: the hovering effect is working with the above transparent fix but why does the whole menu take some space at top and bottom

Comment: because of the 3px border, reduce padding to compensate

Comment: you need margin:0; padding:0; on your ul.

Comment: Look at my 2nd fiddle, I never said to add the padding and margin 0. Once you add the padding/margin 0, the design changes. I assume your design was fine and should not change

Comment: @ Huangism hovering is fixed now but i am trying to remove space on top and bottom of the menu

Comment: is it possible to specify width for each li block insted i use padding but it doesn't suit my content class width

Comment: yeah the space is fixed. :)

Comment: is it possible to specify width for each li block instead i use padding but it doesn't suit my content class width?

Comment: @ShahilM everything is possible but that's up to you to learn. If my answer is correct and solved your problem, I appreciated if you mark it as accepted answer

Comment: if i need to specify width i need t specify width for li and i should remove padding is it?

Comment: @ShahilM I don't know the design you have in mind. There are different approaches to achieve the same thing. Try things out and you will find out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38116/discussion-between-shahil-m-and-huangism)